# LCM of consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

Given L = LCM(1,2,.....,n)
We need to find the largest  'm' such that  m<=n and 
  LCM(m,m+1,.....,n) = L

Any process to do so?

eg.   LCM (1,2,3,4,5) = 60 and LCM (3,4,5) = 60
      So,  for n=5  the answer is m=3

Comment: Do you need an algorithm , or what?

Comment: Easy to see that $m$ is at least $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

Comment: @openspace obviously I need an algorithm.

Comment: @Batominovski I know that but I need a definite value of 'm' given any 'n'

Comment: I know what you need.  Is it wrong for me to state a bound on $m$?  Should I remove everything I posted here because it didn't answer your question?

Comment: @Batominovski No you do not need to remove anything. What you said is an obvious first step and there is nothing wrong in it
Also I did not mean to offend you in first place, sorry anyways

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_n$ be the set of $p^k$ where $p$ is a prime natural number not greater than $n$ and $k$ is the largest positive integer such that $p^k\leq n$.  (Observe that $\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)=\prod_{q\in X_n}\,q$.)  For each $q\in X_n$, let $t_n(q)$ denote the largest multiple of $q$ that is less than or equal to $n$.  Take $Y_n$ for the set of $t_n(q)$ for $q\in X_n$.  Set $a_n:=\min\left(Y_n\right)$ and $b_n:=\max\left(Y_n\right)$.  Then, $$\text{lcm}\left(1,2,\ldots,n\right)=\text{lcm}\left(a_n,a_n+1,\ldots,b_n-1,b_n\right)\,.$$  To answer the OP's question, $m:=a_n$ is the largest such $m$.  I also believe that $\left\{a_n,a_n+1,\ldots,b_n-1,b_n\right\}$ is the smallest interval in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ whose lcm is equal to $\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)$.